# How to seed relationships using code first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, seeding

In my model a Question can have many valid Answers and an Answer can be used on many Questions. I have a unique index on the Answer.Text property to prevent duplicates and ensure validation is efficient. I have this code in my Seed method.

```
   Answer _None = new Answer { Text = "None", SortOrder = 50 };
   context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Text, _None);
   context.SaveChanges();

   Question q = new Question 
   { 
      Text = "Bathroom flooring", 
      Answers = new Answer[] 
               {
                  _None,     
                  new Answer { Text = "Carpet", SortOrder = 60} 
               } 
   }
   context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Text, q);
   context.SaveChanges();
```

The method throws an error because another insert is attempted on the second call to context.SaveChanges() for the answer with text "None". *Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Answers' with unique index 'IX_NaturalKey'*. The duplicate key value is (None)." Why is a second insert attempted when an existing object is added to a relationship and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I tried the code and it worked well.

Comment: Try pulling the _None answer from your context when inserting into your question answers array.  might just be a problem with it not knowing it is in the context

Comment: @sza I am using EF6 release candidate. Perhaps there is a problem with that...In the meantime, since this is likely to be fixed data required in production I have decided to insert the data via sql statements so that I can do the insert in the Up method of a migration, and I have parked the problem for now

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
context.Question.AddOrUpdate(
                p => p.Id,
                new Models.Question
                {
                    Question = "Bathroom flooring",
                    //Active = true,
                    Answers = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Answers>(){
                        new Answers {Id=1, Text = "Carpet",SortOrder=60 },
                        new Answers {Id=2, Text = "Carpet",SortOrder=60 },
            new Answers {Id=3, Text = "Carpet",SortOrder=60 },
            new Answers {Id=4, Text = "Carpet",SortOrder=60 },
            new Answers {Id=5, Text = "Carpet",SortOrder=60 },
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Duplicate Text in the Answers table is not allowed. So lots of "Carpet" answers with different Id's are not allowed. What I want to do is be able to add an answer with the text "None" as a valid answer to more than one question. So I can also have Question.Text = "Kitchen flooring" with Question.Answer = _None

Comment: those texts are example you can change.